# is there a optimized/better way to write this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have below query and wanted to know if this can be re-written in a better way?

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 1 and COL4 = 1415 AND COL3 IN 
(SELECT MAX(COL3) FROM TABLE1 WHERE PRI = ID = 1 and COL4 = 1415);
```

The question arises from the fact that filters ID and Col4 in where clause of subquery are same as the filters in the main query.

Comment: It can be written in a better way, but the best way would also include a subquery

Comment: This seems to be a [_groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
    SELECT COL1, COL2,MAX(COL3) as mx FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 1 
     and COL4 = 1415  having  mx=MAX(COL3);
```

This will avoid the extra sub-query.

Comment: No.  That does not work.  That gets you random values for COL1 and COL2.